# Sum of items in JSONArray doubling on activity relaunch

Tags: android, arrays, networking

I'm using Fast Android Networking library to parse a `JSONArray` generated from my PHP/MySQL API. I'm using a for loop to sum all integer values in the `JSONArray`. Everything works great when I first launch the activity the data is sent to (as static references), but on relaunch, the data is doubled i.e if on first launch sum was 500, on relaunch it returns 1000.

This is the method I use to parse the JSONArray

```
public void getGroupStats() {
    MaterialDialog.Builder builder = new MaterialDialog.Builder(Splash.this)
            .progress(true, 100)
            .content("Loading...")
            .cancelable(false);
    dialog = builder.build();
    dialog.show();

    AndroidNetworking.post(Helper.Header + "/savings/api/Api.php?apicall=getgroups")
            .addBodyParameter("goal", sharedPreferences.getString("Goal", ""))
            .addBodyParameter("type", sharedPreferences.getString("Type", ""))
            .setPriority(Priority.MEDIUM)
            .build()
            .getAsJSONObject(new JSONObjectRequestListener() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = null;

                    try {
                        jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("savings");
                        for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray.length(); j++) {
                            obj = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(j);
                            groupsaving += Integer.parseInt(obj.getString("saving"));
                            groupsaved += Integer.parseInt(obj.getString("saved"));
                            Helper.Members = jsonArray.length();
                        }

                        Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, Statistics.class);
                        intent.putExtra("Title", textView.getText().toString());
                        if (textView.getText().toString().contains("SAVVY SAVER")) {
                            Helper.Image = "smallest_bag";
                        } else if (textView.getText().toString().contains("POWER SAVER")) {
                            Helper.Image = "small_bag";
                        } else if (textView.getText().toString().contains("SUPER SAVER")) {
                            Helper.Image = "big_bag";
                        } else {
                            Helper.Image = "biggest_bag";
                        }
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Helper.GroupSaving = groupsaving;//to be used in next activity
                    Helper.GroupSaved = groupsaved;

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(groupsaved) + " " + String.valueOf(groupsaving), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    dialog.cancel();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(ANError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cant you just make your variables zero before the loop?

Comment: I knew I had to do that but I was doing it at init stage.Relocated to just before the try catch and now its working fine.Thanks man.